# react component not updating state

Tags: reactjs, firebase

When I console log the state it returns undefined but in my react dev tools I can see the resulting array.
this is the component:

```
    var Categorias = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      items: []
    };
  },

componentWillMount: function (){
  var  firebaseRef = new Firebase("https://rapifood.firebaseio.com/categorias");
  firebaseRef.on("child_added", function(dataSnapshot) {
    var items= [];
    items.push(dataSnapshot.val());
    this.setState({
      items: items
    });
  }.bind(this));
},

componentDidMount: function () {
  console.log(this.state.items);
},
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you might want to try putting the `console.log` in the render function. not sure if the data is there yet by the time `componentDidMount` is fired

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are setting state on an ajax callback, which is completing after the initial render (componentDidMount).

Comment: Example of a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna have another state variable to track the loading status:

```
var Categories = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      loaded: false,
      items: []
    };
  },

  componentWillMount: function (){
    var  firebaseRef = new Firebase("https://rapifood.firebaseio.com/categorias");
    firebaseRef.on("child_added", function(dataSnapshot) {
      this.setState({
        loaded: true,
        items: this.state.items.concat(dataSnapshot.val())
      });
    }.bind(this));
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    // Don't forget to remove the Firebase subscription here.
  }

  render: function() {
    if (!this.state.loaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
    // Now you can render the list of items here.
  },
});
```